# Animation with opening of new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to know whether there is any way to animate the opening of new window after clicking a link.  I mean when user clicks on a link, when the respective link opens, it does so under some animation rather than just appearing suddenly.

Comment: Is the link a simple href? or is it some custom JS/Jquery code which opens a dialog/popup ?

Comment: simple href within an anchor tag....if it problems then i can use window.open() method...i just want the opening to be animated whatever i need to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `<head>` of your target page (the page pointed to by the link):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You saved my days...Thanksssssssssssssssss stay blesses :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an API that you could follow and animate your windows

Link for ref: [JQuery Aminate API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)